# Resolution of iPhone app created with PhoneGap

Tags: iphone, cordova, resolution

I have some problems when putting images in my iPhone app using PhoneGap.
According to [this](http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/sizes.html) website the width of any iPhone screen is 320pts.

In my CSS I have the following code:

```
#someId {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px; 
    left:0; 

    max-width:640px;
    max-height: auto;
}
```

And in my HTML file the following snippet:

```
<img src="image.png" id="someId" alt="">
```

However, if I leave it like this, the image will always be bigger than the actual screen. I'm using the iPhone 6.0 Simulator.
Changing the value of `max-width` to 320pt doesn't change anything.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

Because so many websites are designed assuming a typical desktop-sized browser window, Mobile Safari renders pages at the default width of 980 pixels.  To override this default so that it only renders websites at the width of the screen, use the following `<meta>` element:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my problem. I'm actually talking about an actual app, created with PhoneGap using HTML/CSS/JS. It doesn't open Safari, at all. I tried putting your snippet in my code nonetheless, but, as expected, nothing changed.